# SQL temp table vs physical (actual) table performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance, temp-tables

Observed performance difference between #temp table vs physical(actual) table while performing bulk insert operation into these tables with same numbers of records(~50 million).

With (Insert into... select) query, temp table takes ~ 3 minutes and physical table takes ~ 8 minutes.

Here, physical table is exact same as temp table.(physical table is without cluster and non-clustered indexes).

Why is temp table preforming more efficiently and better than physical table? Does anyone have some context on it?

Comment: Perhaps the temporary table space is on a more efficient set of disks.

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans? Are your tables *really* 100% identical, down to the exact data types and lengths (in the case of char/varchar)?

Comment: Check which recovery mode is set for your database. Most probably, it's `full`. Tempdb is always in `simple` mode, meaning bulk operations are minimally logged. This translates into less write load for transaction logs, compared to `full` mode.

Comment: btw, insert into... is not minimally logged, unless OP specifies 'with (TABLOCK)'.   Also we need to keep in mind that if CDC is enabled for DB, all operations are fully logged, even when Recovery Model is simple.

Comment: Yes tables are same with all datatype and length as well.

Comment: tried TABLOCK as well. don't find any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors:

- data and log file location / configuration
- fragmentation
- autogrowth settings
- IO performance
  etc

It is likely tempdb is less fragmented as it was recreated during server restart or (as mentioned above) tempdb is on more efficient set of disks